# EF Core параллельная запись в БД через Task

Tags: c#, async-await, entity-framework-core, task

Есть файл который считывается порционно, каждая порция возвращается через **yield return**, затем должен запускаться **Task** отвечающий за запись считанных строк в БД, используя **EF Core**. Проблема заключается в том что нельзя на одном контексте запускать несколько операций сразу.

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
   foreach (var portion in reader.ReadPortions(file, 1000))
      tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => await saver.SaveWithMerge(portion)));

   Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Как это можно решить?

Comment: Лучше всего использовать Bulk Insert.

Comment: Это конечно было бы хорошо, но есть нюансы: сущность не имеет первичного ключа и сохранение происходит не просто вставкой, идет проверка по нескольким полям, а далее либо добавление нового элемента либо обновление старого.

Comment: _проверка по нескольким полям_ - проверка происходит где: на клиенте или в самой БД? / Контекстов можно создавать сколько угодно. / Есть стандартный способ выполнения таких действий: паттерн Producer/Consumer. / Эффективный upsert в разных СУБД реализуется по-разному. Укажите используемую СУБД.

Comment: Проверка на клиенте; postgesql; Пытался создавать контексты на каждое действие сохранения, через IDbContextFactory, в таком случае быстро забивается оперативная память.

Comment: _быстро забивается оперативная память_ - ну и пусть забивается, что с того? / Я бы сразу смотрел в сторону Producer/Consumer: один task читает из файла и кидает данные в очередь/канал; другой task делает проверки, кидает данные в другой канал; третий task пишет данные в БД.

Comment: Думаю, основной затык именно в записи. Всё же нужно применять bulk-операции. Я бы взял какое-нибудь расширение EF для этой цели. Например, [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore). Оно в официальном списке [EF Core Tools & Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/) (можно любое другое на свой вкус оттуда выбрать). Документация здесь: [Bulk Copy (Bulk Insert)](https://linq2db.github.io/articles/sql/Bulk-Copy.html)

Comment: Пойду разбирать с producer/consumer, спасибо за наводку. По память и другое: есть ограничения от лида (максимальное потребление памяти - 1гб, время выполнения на файле с 1M записей не более часа).